# Custom tokenizer for scikit-learn vectorizers

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Given the following list of documents:

```
docs = [
'feature one`feature two`feature three',
'feature one`feature two`feature four',
'feature one'
]
```

I want to use either of the vectorizer classes in scikit (`CountVectorizer` or `TfidfVectorizer`), with `'feature one'`, `'feature two'`, `'feature three'`, and `'feature four'` should be the four features represented in the matrix.

I tried this:

```
vec = CountVectorizer(token_pattern='(?u)\w+\s.\w.`')
```

But that returns only this:

```
['feature one`', 'feature two`']
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? It's not clear. Does the back-tick character have a special meaning for you?

Comment: I've used the back-tick character as a custom separation character. No different from using commas to separate fields in a CSV, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [295]: vec = CountVectorizer(token_pattern='(?u)\w+[\s\`]\w+')

In [296]: X = vec.fit_transform(docs)

In [297]: vec.get_feature_names()
Out[297]: ['feature four', 'feature one', 'feature three', 'feature two']
```

you may also want to consider using `ngram_range=(2,2)`, which would produce the following:

```
In [308]: vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2))

In [309]: X = vec.fit_transform(docs)

In [310]: vec.get_feature_names()
Out[310]:
['feature four',
 'feature one',
 'feature three',
 'feature two',
 'one feature',
 'two feature']
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the middle `[\s\`]` piece? Does that match either a whitespace character or a ``` char?

Comment: @blacksite, yep, you would need to extend it if needs to accept other characters as well...

Answer (score 2):

If you have fixed the features to be

```
'feature one', 'feature two', 'feature three', and 'feature four'
```

then you can also use the `vocabulary` param.

```
vocab = ['feature one', 'feature two', 'feature three', 'feature four']
vec = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab)

X = vec.fit_transform(docs)
vec.get_feature_names()
Out[310]:
['feature one',
 'feature two',
 'feature three',
 'feature four']
```